# Tomcat 9 - application/json was not found

Tags: json, tomcat, restful, jersey

Saudações,

Estou desenvolvendo um WS em Jersey/Restful o qual esta funcionando corretamente no Glassfish mas no Tomcat recebo o erro ao tentar consumir o serviço.

> GRAVE: Mapped exception to response: 500 (Internal Server Error)
>   javax.ws.rs.WebApplicationException: com.sun.jersey.api.MessageException: A message body writer for Java class java.util.ArrayList, and Java type java.util.ArrayList, and MIME media type application/json was not found
>       at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponse.write(ContainerResponse.java:285)
>       at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1437)

Só ocorre com produces "application/json" ou MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON já com "text/html" não dá erro no tomcat.

alguém já passou por isso?!

[]´s

Comment: Poderia postar seu código e arquivo de configuração?

Comment: Me desculpe, não havia notado seu comentário... mas já descobri o problema... veja abaixo... Obrigado !

Answer (score 0):

Bom.. Convertendo o ArrayList para String com Gson consegui obter sucesso, mas fiquei intrigado e pesquisando descobri que apenas incluindo genson no projeto o meu problema seria resolvido ... e foi!.

A explicação...

> Precisamos dizer Jersey que a classe java deve ser convertida para Json, verificando especificações como setter / getter classes, se presente ou não.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.owlike</groupId>
        <artifactId>genson</artifactId>
        <version>1.3</version>
    </dependency>
```

O que não entendi foi o por que disso ser preciso apenas Tomcat já que no Glassfish rodou sem erro... mas fica para outra pesquisa...

[]´s

fonte :https://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-rs/json-example-with-jersey-jackson/ (em perguntas e repostas da matéria)